# Passing in constructor values into a method?

Tags: python

I'm working on this program where I'm trying to create get and post methods. The method I'm using is from an outside module and it takes the record values, and pushes them into the database.

I figure I have to find a way to pass in my constructor values. So far it's something like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a=0, b=0, c="", ... , toggle_on=False):
        # constructors defined here
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        # ...
        self.toggle_on = toggle_on

    # ... some other methods in between

    def insert_stuff(self, **kwargs):
        sess.add(MyTableClass(**kwargs))
```

Is there a way to pass in the constructor values in that manner?

Comment: Could you enlighten your question?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke What? camelCase is not what PEP8 recommends for class names. That would be TitleCase, which the OP got right.

Comment: @Eithos: I think that is not too well defined :-) Quote from PEP8: *"CapitalizedWords (or CapWords, or CamelCase"*. What I have called camelCase here actually is called *"mixedCase"* in PEP8. I have deleted my comment, nevertheless, because arguably I should have criticized his use of mixedCase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create the `MyTableClass` instance before calling the `insert_stuff()` method? Looks much cleaner to me:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self._session = ...

    def insert_stuff(self, table):
        self._session.add(table)


c = MyClass(...)
t = MyTableClass(...)
c.insert_stuff(t)
```